# Why LinkedHashSet has boolean accessOrder set to false

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashset

In Java LinkedHashSet is created with backing HashSet creating LinkedHashMap with following LinkedHashMap constructor

```
map = new LinkedHashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
```

Now in LinkedHashMap, the above constructor in turn calls

```
 public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    super(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    accessOrder = false;
}
```

so is there any way to have a LinkedHashSet with `accessOrder` set to `true`?
This can help create LRU cache implementation with LinkedHashSet.

Comment: I'm asking about LinkedHashSet.

Comment: The default is indeed the order of _insertion_, not access. As for map, `put` can overwrite a previous entry, hence order of _access_ is more important - I guess.

Comment: If all else fails, use reflection ;)

Comment: @Marvin It's the fall back plan. But thinking loud what could be the rationale for not providing the option of setting the accessOrder for LinkedHashSet

Comment: Sure! I'm also curious.

Answer (score 3):

`LinkedHashSet` doesn't support access order, since you are not accessing elements of a `LinkedHashSet`.

You add elements to the `LinkedHashSet`, and you can iterate over them in insertion order.

When you check if an element is a member of the `LinkedHashSet`, you are not accessing it. You check membership via `boolean contains(Object o)`, calls `map.containsKey(o)` for the backing map. However, `containsKey()` doesn't affect the access order of the `Map`.

On the other hand, the `get(Object key)` method of `LinkedHashMap` does affect access order, but it is never used by `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: Actually, no. "put" is considered an access. The choice of the word "access" in the official docs seems to imply otherwise, and it is not obvious from the LinkedHashMap documentation, but several boring re-reads you'll see it, it's in there.

Comment: Just FYI: "Invoking the put or get method results in an access to the corresponding entry (assuming it exists after the invocation completes)." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap(int,%20float,%20boolean)  I assume that the implementors of (Linked)HashSet simply missed this, or it was changed after LinkedHashSet was implemented.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the source code, a LinkedHashSet is backed by a LinkedHashMap with the accessOrder set to false.

Furthermore, there is no public constructor for LinkedHashSet to change the access order from insertion order to access order.

You could try this (just an example):

```
LinkedHashSet<E> set = (LinkedHashSet<E>) Collections.newSetFromMap(new LinkedHashMap<>(16, 0.75f, true));
```

Comment: OP wants to create a `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: I want to create an object of LinkedHashSet not LinkedHashMap

Comment: agreed, hence the question if there is any hack to create LRU cache using LinkedHashSet in Java

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source code?  I can't find it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashSet.java

Comment: @Dsenese1 this will not work, as the returned Set is almost certainly not an instance of `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: It could have worked! :) You could override the internal map in the constructor, but no, "map" is private, not protected. Basically, the Java implementors have ensured that it is absolutely impossible to create an access-ordered LinkedHashSet without completely reimplementing it.